# Combining two lists by key using Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Given two key-value lists, I am trying to combine the two sides by matching the keys and applying a function to the two values when the keys match. In my case I want to multiply the values. A small example to make it more clear:

```
Left keys:   { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 }
Left values: { 3, 4, 1, 2, 1 }

Right keys:   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
Right values: { 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2 };

Expected output keys:   { 1, 4, 5, 6 }
Expected output values: { 6, 1, 8, 1 }
```

I have been able to implement this on the CPU using C++ using the next code:

```
int main() {
    int leftKeys[5] =   { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
    int leftValues[5] = { 3, 4, 1, 2, 1 };
    int rightKeys[6] =   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int rightValues[6] = { 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2 };

    int leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> result;
    while (leftIndex < 5 && rightIndex < 6) {
        if (leftKeys[leftIndex] < rightKeys[rightIndex]) {
            leftIndex++;
        }
        if (leftKeys[leftIndex] > rightKeys[rightIndex]) {
            rightIndex++;
        }
        result.push_back(std::make_tuple(leftKeys[leftIndex], leftValues[leftIndex] * rightValues[rightIndex]));
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex++;
    }

    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << std::get<0>(result[i]) << "; Value: " << std::get<1>(result[i]) << "\n";
    }
}
```

However, I have the input keys and values in Thrust's `device_vector`s and I need the results on the GPU as well. Therefore it would be more efficient if I did not need to copy all inputs to the host and all outputs back to the device.

The problem is that I cannot find a Thrust function that can be used to combine two lists using a set of keys (and apply a function to both values). Does such a function exist or is there an easy way to implement it myself of should I just do this on the host?

**Update:**

The following assumptions can be made about the input:

- The keys are always sorted.
- No duplicate keys exist within a single list (between the lists, duplicate keys of course do exist, otherwise the result would be empty).

**Update 2:**

While implementing the second approach in @Robert's answer I get stuck at the transformation. My code so far is below:

```
struct multiply_transformation : public thrust::binary_function<std::tuple<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int>>
{
    __host__ __device__
        thrust::tuple<int, int> operator()(thrust::tuple<int, int> d_left, thrust::tuple<int, int> d_right)
    {
        if (thrust::get<0>(d_left) == thrust::get<0>(d_right)) {
            return thrust::make_tuple(thrust::get<0>(d_left), thrust::get<1>(d_left) * thrust::get<1>(d_right));
        }
        return thrust::make_tuple(-1, -1);
    }
};


thrust::device_vector<int> d_mergedKeys(h_leftCount + h_rightCount);
thrust::device_vector<int> d_mergedValues(h_leftCount + h_rightCount);
thrust::merge_by_key(d_leftCountKeys.begin(), d_leftCountKeys.begin() + h_leftCount,
    d_rightCountKeys.begin(), d_rightCountKeys.begin() + h_rightCount,
    d_leftCounts.begin(), d_rightCounts.begin(), d_mergedKeys.begin(), d_mergedValues.begin());

typedef thrust::tuple<int, int> IntTuple;
thrust::zip_iterator<IntTuple> d_zippedCounts(thrust::make_tuple(d_mergedKeys.begin(), d_mergedValues.begin()));
thrust::zip_iterator<IntTuple> d_zippedCountsOffset(d_zippedCounts + 1);

multiply_transformation transformOperator;
thrust::device_vector<IntTuple> d_transformedResult(h_leftCount + h_rightCount);
thrust::transform(d_zippedCounts, d_zippedCounts + h_leftCount + h_rightCount - 1, d_zippedCountsOffset, d_transformedResult.begin(), transformOperator);
```

However, I get the error that no overloaded function `thrust::transform` matches the argument list. In the above code `h_leftCount` and `h_rightCount` are the sizes of the left and right inputs. `d_leftCountKeys`, `d_rightCountKeys`, `d_leftCounts`, and `d_rightCounts` are `thrust::device_vector<int>`.

Comment: are the keys always in sorted order?  Obviously there can be duplicate keys between the two lists, but do duplicate keys ever appear within a single list (Left or Right)?  If so, how should that case be handled?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes, the keys are always sorted and no duplicates will exist. I will update the question with assumptions that can be made.

Comment: There are probably a few problems with the code you have posted.  I get quite a few errors when I try to compile a complete code around it.   It's probably better if you provide an MCVE for help with specific coding errors.   1. You are mixing `std::tuple` and `thrust::tuple` in your struct.  2. A `zip_iterator` has a type that is a tuple of iterators, not a tuple of basic types.  [These modifications](http://pastebin.com/k3s0e5NC) to your code allow me to compile cleanly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure this is the best method (@m.s. usually comes up with better approaches than I), but one possible approach would be (method 1):

1. [set_intersection_by_key](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__set__operations.html)(Left,Right)
2. set_intersection_by_key(Right,Left)
3. Take the values outputs from step 1 and step 2, and perform a [transform](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#ga68a3ba7d332887f1332ca3bc04453792) on them to multiply the values results together (or whatever other mathematical operation you'd like to perform on the corresponding values results from step 1 and step 2).

I don't know what your skill level is with [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) but I can provide a trivial worked example of the above if desired.

Another possible approach (method 2):

1. [merge_by_key](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__merging.html) the two lists together
2. Perform a transform using two versions of the resultant list from step 1:  The first consisting of [first, last-1) and the second consisting of [first+1, last).  This will require a special functor that takes a zipped version of the keys and values, and compares the two keys presented.  If it is a match, output the desired mathematical operation on the two presented values; if it is not a match, output some kind of marker or known illegal value. (If such an illegal value is impossible to construct, we can zip a 3rd marker array in if needed.)
3. Do a [remove_if](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html)  on the output of step 2, to compact the result down to the desired result, removing all value entries that are illegal, or else removing all value entries that are indicated by the marker array.

My sense is the second method might be faster, but I haven't carefully thought through it.  In any event, it's better to benchmark test cases than to work off of (my) intuition.

Based on a comment below, here is a description of what is happening starting with the 2nd step of method 2, using your example dataset:

The output of step 1 (the merge_by_key operation) would look like something like this:

```
keys:   { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
values: { 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2 };
```

Let's construct two versions, the first being "the item" and the second being "the next item to the right":

```
keys1:   { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6 };
values1: { 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1 };

keys2:   { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
values2: { 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2 };
```

The actual "construction" is trivial.  keys1 is just [keys.begin(), keys.end()-1), and keys2 is just [keys.begin()+1, keys.end()).  And likewise for values1 and values2.

We'll zip keys1 and values1 together and we'll zip keys2 and values2 together.  Then we'll pass these two zipped entities to a transform operation that has a special functor that will do the following:

If keys1 == keys2, do the desired math operation on the values1 and values2 quantities, and place a one in the marker array.  If not, place a 0 in a marker array.  The output of this operation would be:

```
 keys:   { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
 values: { 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 8, 4, 1, 1, 2 };
 marker: { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
```

Now zip the 3 vectors above together, and pass that to remove_if.  The remove_if functor would indicate removal of any items for which marker == 0, leaving:

```
 keys:   { 1, 4, 5, 6 };
 values: { 6, 1, 8, 1 };
 marker: { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

Here is a fully worked example demonstrating both methods:

```
$ cat t1007.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/merge.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct mark_mpy_func
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(T1 &z1, T2 &z2){
    int res = 0;
    if (thrust::get<0>(z1) == thrust::get<0>(z2)){
      res = thrust::get<1>(z1) * thrust::get<1>(z2);
      thrust::get<2>(z1) = 1;}
    return res;
    }
};

struct mtest_func
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(int t){
    if (t == 0) return true;
    return false;
    }
};

int main(){

  int Lkeys[] =   { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
  int Lvals[] =   { 3, 4, 1, 2, 1 };
  int Rkeys[] =   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  int Rvals[] =   { 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2 };

  size_t Lsize = sizeof(Lkeys)/sizeof(int);
  size_t Rsize = sizeof(Rkeys)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int> Lkeysv(Lkeys, Lkeys+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Lvalsv(Lvals, Lvals+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rkeysv(Rkeys, Rkeys+Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rvalsv(Rvals, Rvals+Rsize);

  // method 1

  thrust::device_vector<int> Lkeysvo(Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Lvalsvo(Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rkeysvo(Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rvalsvo(Rsize);

  size_t Lsizeo = thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), Lvalsv.begin(), Lkeysvo.begin(), Lvalsvo.begin()).first - Lkeysvo.begin();
  size_t Rsizeo = thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rvalsv.begin(), Rkeysvo.begin(), Rvalsvo.begin()).first - Rkeysvo.begin();

  assert(Lsizeo == Rsizeo);
  thrust::device_vector<int> res1(Lsizeo);
  thrust::transform(Lvalsvo.begin(), Lvalsvo.begin()+Lsizeo, Rvalsvo.begin(), res1.begin(), thrust::multiplies<int>());

  std::cout << "Method 1 result:" << std::endl << "keys: ";
  thrust::copy_n(Lkeysvo.begin(), Lsizeo, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "vals: ";
  thrust::copy_n(res1.begin(), Lsizeo, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // method 2

  thrust::device_vector<int> Mkeysv(Lsize + Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Mvalsv(Lsize + Rsize);

  thrust::merge_by_key(Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), Lvalsv.begin(), Rvalsv.begin(), Mkeysv.begin(), Mvalsv.begin());
  thrust::device_vector<int> marker(Lsize + Rsize - 1);
  thrust::device_vector<int> res2(Lsize + Rsize - 1);
  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin(), Mvalsv.begin(), marker.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.end()-1, Mvalsv.end()-1, marker.end())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin()+1, Mvalsv.begin()+1)), res2.begin(), mark_mpy_func());
  size_t rsize2 = thrust::remove_if(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple( Mkeysv.begin(), res2.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.end()-1, res2.end())), marker.begin(), mtest_func()) - thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin(), res2.begin()));
  std::cout << "Method 2 result:" << std::endl << "keys: ";
  thrust::copy_n(Mkeysv.begin(), rsize2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "vals: ";
  thrust::copy_n(res2.begin(), rsize2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;


  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t1007 t1007.cu
$ ./t1007
Method 1 result:
keys: 1,4,5,6,
vals: 6,1,8,1,
Method 2 result:
keys: 1,4,5,6,
vals: 6,1,8,1,
$
```

If it is acceptable to use a marker value (say, -1) in the output data to inform the remove_if operation, then the separate marker array can be dispensed with.  Here's a modified version of method 2 that works this way:

```
$ cat t1007.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/merge.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>

#define MARK_VAL -1

struct mark_mpy_func
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(T1 &z1, T2 &z2){
    int res = MARK_VAL;
    if (thrust::get<0>(z1) == thrust::get<0>(z2)){
      res = thrust::get<1>(z1) * thrust::get<1>(z2);}
    return res;
    }
};

struct mtest_func
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T t){
    if (thrust::get<1>(t) == MARK_VAL) return true;
    return false;
    }
};

int main(){

  int Lkeys[] =   { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
  int Lvals[] =   { 3, 4, 1, 2, 1 };
  int Rkeys[] =   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  int Rvals[] =   { 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2 };

  size_t Lsize = sizeof(Lkeys)/sizeof(int);
  size_t Rsize = sizeof(Rkeys)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int> Lkeysv(Lkeys, Lkeys+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Lvalsv(Lvals, Lvals+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rkeysv(Rkeys, Rkeys+Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rvalsv(Rvals, Rvals+Rsize);

  // method 2

  thrust::device_vector<int> Mkeysv(Lsize + Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Mvalsv(Lsize + Rsize);

  thrust::merge_by_key(Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), Lvalsv.begin(), Rvalsv.begin(), Mkeysv.begin(), Mvalsv.begin());
  thrust::device_vector<int> res2(Lsize + Rsize - 1);
  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin(), Mvalsv.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.end()-1, Mvalsv.end()-1)), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin()+1, Mvalsv.begin()+1)), res2.begin(), mark_mpy_func());
  size_t rsize2 = thrust::remove_if(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple( Mkeysv.begin(), res2.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.end()-1, res2.end())), mtest_func()) - thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Mkeysv.begin(), res2.begin()));
  std::cout << "Method 2 result:" << std::endl << "keys: ";
  thrust::copy_n(Mkeysv.begin(), rsize2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "vals: ";
  thrust::copy_n(res2.begin(), rsize2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;


  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t1007 t1007.cu
$ ./t1007
Method 2 result:
keys: 1,4,5,6,
vals: 6,1,8,1,
$
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand how to implement your first approach. However, I am not sure I understand your second approach. Specifically, I do not get what is happening in the second step.

Comment: I've added some additional description around method 2. If you need a worked example, I can probably cook one up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I get it now. I am going to try and implement this and will accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I ran into some problems implementing your second approach. I cannot get the transformation on the zipped lists to work. Could you please provide some guidance?

Comment: I've added a worked example of both methods.  Note that the `mtest_func` could easily be eliminated using thrust placeholders.

Comment: Thanks. I have gotten both methods to work with your code. At least in my case, your intuition was right: the second method was faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do all you want using **one** `thrust::set_intersection_by_key` call.
However, some prerequisites need to be met:

First, the easy one:

You need to **zip** `Lvalsv` and `Rvalsv` into a single `thrust::zip_iterator` and pass this as the values to [`thrust::set_intersection_by_key`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__set__operations.html#gac9db7cdc6dc16466f46f8cdd29a4310e).

You could already run this:

```
std::size_t min_size = std::min(Lsize, Rsize);
thrust::device_vector<int> result_keys(min_size);
thrust::device_vector<int> result_values_left(min_size);
thrust::device_vector<int> result_values_right(min_size);

auto zipped_input_values = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Lvalsv.begin(), Rvalsv.begin()));
auto zipped_output_values = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(result_values_left.begin(), result_values_right.begin()));

auto result_pair = thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), zipped_input_values, result_keys.begin(), zipped_output_values);
```

This would yield two result vectors, which you would need to multiply element-wise to get your final result.

But wait, wouldn't it be great if you could avoid having to store these two vectors as the result, then read each element again for multiplying them and then store the final result in a third vector?

Let's do that. The concept I adapted is from [here](https://github.com/ldionne/boost-submissions/blob/master/boost/boost/iterator/transform_output_iterator.hpp).
The `transform_output_iterator` is a iterator, which is a wrapper around another `OutputIterator`. When writing to the `transform_output_iterator`, a `UnaryFunction` is applied to the value to be written, then that result is written to the wrapped `OutputIterator`.

This allows us to pass the result from `thrust::set_intersection_by_key` through the `Multiplier` functor and then store it in the results in a single `result_values` vector.

The following code implements this idea:

```
#include <thrust/iterator/iterator_traits.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/iterator_facade.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/iterator_adaptor.h>

#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>  
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryFunction>
class Proxy
{
    UnaryFunction& fun;
    OutputIterator& out;

public:
    __host__ __device__
    Proxy(UnaryFunction& fun, OutputIterator& out) : fun(fun), out(out) {}

    template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__
    Proxy operator=(const T& x) const
    {
        *out = fun(x);
        return *this;
    }
};


// This iterator is a wrapper around another OutputIterator which
// applies a UnaryFunction before writing to the OutputIterator.
template <typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryFunction>
class transform_output_iterator : public thrust::iterator_adaptor<
                                    transform_output_iterator<OutputIterator, UnaryFunction>
                                                                      , OutputIterator
                                      , thrust::use_default
                                      , thrust::use_default
                                      , thrust::use_default
                                                                      , Proxy<const OutputIterator, const UnaryFunction> >
{
    UnaryFunction fun;

public:

    friend class thrust::iterator_core_access;

    // shorthand for the name of the iterator_adaptor we're deriving from
    typedef thrust::iterator_adaptor<
      transform_output_iterator<OutputIterator, UnaryFunction>,
      OutputIterator, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default, Proxy<const OutputIterator, const UnaryFunction>
    > super_t;

    __host__ __device__
    transform_output_iterator(OutputIterator out, UnaryFunction fun) : super_t(out), fun(fun)
    {
    }


private:
    __host__ __device__
    typename super_t::reference dereference() const
    {
        return Proxy<const OutputIterator, const UnaryFunction>(fun, this->base_reference());
    }
};


struct Multiplier
{
    template<typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
    auto operator()(Tuple t) const -> decltype(thrust::get<0>(t) * thrust::get<1>(t))
    {
        return thrust::get<0>(t) * thrust::get<1>(t);
    }
};


template <typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryFunction>
transform_output_iterator<OutputIterator, UnaryFunction>
__host__ __device__
make_transform_output_iterator(OutputIterator out, UnaryFunction fun)
{
    return transform_output_iterator<OutputIterator, UnaryFunction>(out, fun);
}

int main()
{
  int Lkeys[] =   { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
  int Lvals[] =   { 3, 4, 1, 2, 1 };
  int Rkeys[] =   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  int Rvals[] =   { 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2 };

  size_t Lsize = sizeof(Lkeys)/sizeof(int);
  size_t Rsize = sizeof(Rkeys)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int> Lkeysv(Lkeys, Lkeys+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Lvalsv(Lvals, Lvals+Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rkeysv(Rkeys, Rkeys+Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rvalsv(Rvals, Rvals+Rsize);

  std::size_t min_size = std::min(Lsize, Rsize);

  thrust::device_vector<int> result_keys(min_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> result_values(min_size);

  auto zipped_values = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Lvalsv.begin(), Rvalsv.begin()));

  auto output_it = make_transform_output_iterator(result_values.begin(), Multiplier());

  auto result_pair = thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Lkeysv.begin(), Lkeysv.end(), Rkeysv.begin(), Rkeysv.end(), zipped_values, result_keys.begin(), output_it);

  std::size_t new_size = result_pair.first - result_keys.begin();

  result_keys.resize(new_size);
  result_values.resize(new_size);
  PRINTER(result_keys);
  PRINTER(result_values);
}
```

**output**

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 main.cu && ./a.out

result_keys:    1   4   5   6   
result_values:  6   1   8   1
```

Comment: You could also just multiply all the values via a transform_iterator, then pass that as the values for the first set passed to set_intersection_by_key

Comment: @RobertCrovella not sure how that would work, could you post an example?

Comment: I've added an example of what I had in mind.  However I think your work on the output iterator is *very good*.  A transform wrapper on an output iterator would be useful in many situations.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks,  I will add this as a pull request on github after a bit of polishing.

Comment: @m.s I'm quite interested in your transform output iterator. Did you ever add it to github? If so, could you post a pointer to it?

Comment: @AlltheRage yes, the code is merged into thrust: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/iterator/transform_output_iterator.h

Answer (score 1):

I think two set intersections are required, as suggested in the first answer. The other solutions won't work, and it is just coincidence in the input data they produce correct result. For example, if the second (key,value) pair is removed from the left set, the computed result will be different while it shouldn't Here is the code:

```
$ cat inner_join.cu
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int _Lkeys[] = {1, 4, 5, 6};
  int _Lvals[] = {3, 1, 2, 1};
  int _Rkeys[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  int _Rvals[] = {2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2};

  size_t Lsize = sizeof(_Lkeys) / sizeof(int);
  size_t Rsize = sizeof(_Rkeys) / sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int> Lkeys(_Lkeys, _Lkeys + Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Lvals(_Lvals, _Lvals + Lsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rkeys(_Rkeys, _Rkeys + Rsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rvals(_Rvals, _Rvals + Rsize);

  std::size_t min_size = std::min(Lsize, Rsize);

  thrust::device_vector<int> result_keys(min_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> result_Rvals(min_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> result_Lvals(min_size);

  // set intersection keys, and  left set values
  size_t intersection_size =
      thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Lkeys.begin(), Lkeys.end(), Rkeys.begin(),
                                      Rkeys.end(), Lvals.begin(),
                                      result_keys.begin(), result_Lvals.begin())
          .first -
      result_keys.begin();

  // set intersection keys, and  right set values
  thrust::set_intersection_by_key(Rkeys.begin(), Rkeys.end(), Lkeys.begin(),
                                  Lkeys.end(), Rvals.begin(),
                                  result_keys.begin(), result_Rvals.begin());

  result_Lvals.resize(intersection_size);
  result_keys.resize(intersection_size);

  thrust::device_vector<int> result_values(intersection_size);

  // join left and right intersection values
  thrust::transform(result_Lvals.begin(), result_Lvals.end(),
                    result_Rvals.begin(), result_values.begin(),
                    thrust::multiplies<int>());

  std::cout << "keys: ";
  thrust::copy_n(result_keys.begin(), intersection_size,
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "vals: ";
  thrust::copy_n(result_values.begin(), intersection_size,
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**output**

```
$ nvcc inner_join.cu -run
keys: 1,4,5,6,
vals: 6,1,8,1,
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.  I agree that the last method I presented does not work correctly (I'm not sure what I was thinking there.) I have removed that from my answer. I think the remaining two methods (the dual intersection-by-key, and the merge-by-key method) do work however. I have tested them with your suggested data set modification and they seem to produce the correct result. Plus I think both algorithms make sense